# Why are Jenkins and Android Studio having different results on building an android project with gradle?

Tags: android-studio, jenkins, gradle

I am working on a jenkins build server for an android project that uses gradle as build-tool.

The jenkins job checkouts the same git branch as my android studio project and tries to build but fails at one point whereas when I build the project with android studio, I do not get any errors. Where could be reason for this?

Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  >   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9fe834a1339d0af409079f662a365996\res\drawable\abc_btn_colored_material.xml: error: file not found.

There is no error when I build the project with android studio :(

Comment: I see 2 reason that this could happen. First one would be Jenkins builds a different commit than you. Second one would be your build system is configured differently. The exception is saying it is missing a file. Are you sure that this one is also checked out?

Comment: thank you for replying. I am pretty sure they both checked out the same Branch. How could the build system be configured differently? what could be different?